# Convert string into Array in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, postman

I send an array from rest client and received it like this: `"[1,2,3,4,5]"`

Now I just want to convert it into Array without using Ruby's `eval`  method. Any Ruby's default method that we could use for this?

```
 "[1,2,3,4,5]" => [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: Does the API use a specific format like JSON or YAML?

Comment: ...because if not, consider adopting one, you need a serialization format anyway.

Comment: API uses JOSN format

Comment: @GhulamJilani you should strongly consider using Ruby's JSON library as shown in [Cary Swoveland's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35009299/477037) below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps this?

```
   s.tr('[]', '').split(',').map(&:to_i)
```

Comment: Caution: This approach effectively flattens multidimensional arrays.

Comment: With using `'["12", "45"]'.tr('[]','').map(&:to_i)` it return error : `undefined method map`

Comment: tbh, at this point, you should just use `JSON.parse` lol. But if you reallyyyyy wanted, `'["12", "45"]'.tr('["]','').split(',')`

Comment: 2nd caution: If you want it to raise an `ArgumentError` for non-integers like `'2.2'` or bad data like `'2sdf'` then replace the `.map(&:to_i)` at the end with `.map { |x| Integer(x) }`. (Or `.map { |x| Float(x) }` if you want floats).

Answer (score 66):

```
require 'json'

JSON.parse "[1,2,3,4,5]"
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 

JSON.parse "[[1,2],3,4]"
  #=> [[1, 2], 3, 4]
```

Comment: this one should be the accepted answer considering its votes

Comment: @M.Habib agreed it covers any scenario from "[1,2,3]" to '["it covers", "any,scenario",["this","too"]]'

Answer (score 5):

If you want to avoid `eval`, yet another way:

```
"[1,2,3,4,5]".scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i) #assuming you have integer Array as String
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Using this `'[88,89,100]'.scan(/\d/)` returns `["8", "8", "8", "9", "1", "0", "0"]`

Comment: @VishwasNahar tweaking pattern to `\d+` will solve this. I have updated my answer. Thanks

Comment: PS: you should definitely use `JSON.parse` @VishwasNahar