# How to convert a string to an array in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

I have a string looks like an array `"[12,34,35,231]"` But this is just a string contains square brackets at the begin and the end of it.

I need to separate strings looks like arrays and others.

To do this I want to convert a string to an array `'12','34','35','231'` and after conversion use it with the condition like this:

```
if array.is_a? Array
...
else
...
end
```

Could enybody tell me how to do that conversion in the right way?

Comment: `string[1..-2].split(',')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string into Array in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35008941/convert-string-into-array-in-rails)

Comment: Where does that string come from?

Comment: @SagarPandya Yes, you are right, it duplicates that link. Thank you, and everyone for answers. I would like to remove my question, but I can't do it by technical reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use json to convert it to an array.

```
class T
  require 'json'
  def array_detect(array_string)
    begin
      json = JSON.parse array_string
      if json.is_a? Array
        # is an array
      else
        # not an array
      end
    rescue JSON::ParserError => e
      puts e.message
      # not a valid json string
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

It is not conversion, it is parsing.

The input string looks like [JSON](http://json.org). If it is JSON then use the [JSON](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html) Ruby module to decode it:

```
require 'json'
arr = JSON.parse("[12,34,35,231]")
```

`arr` is an array of numbers:

```
p arr
# [12, 34, 35, 231]
```

If you need the values as strings you can use method [`to_s`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Object.html#method-i-to_s) to convert them to strings:

```
arr = arr.map(&:to_s)
p arr
# ["12", "34", "35", "231"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"[12,34,35,231]"[1...-1].split(',')
```

Comment: `each(&:to_s)` makes no difference.

Comment: @SagarPandya right. My mistake, thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
str = "[12,34,35,231]"

str.split(/\D+/).reject(&:empty?)
 => ["12", "34", "35", "231"]

# If you want the elements as numbers instead of strings, do:
str.split(/\D+/).reject(&:empty?).map(&:to_i)
 => [12, 34, 35, 231]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.