# How do I turn my string into an array? (JSON.parse errors)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, json, ruby

How do I turn a string that resembles an array into an actual array?  This thread advised that I should use `JSON.parse` -- [Convert string into Array in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35008941/convert-string-into-array-in-rails), but when I go to try that, I get an error

```
localhost:nightminer satishp$ rails console
Running via Spring preloader in process 9674
Loading development environment (Rails 5.0.6)
irb(main):001:0> JSON.parse("['2de33']")
JSON::ParserError: 409: unexpected token at ''2de33']'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.2_1/lib/ruby/2.4./json/common.rb:156:in `parse'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.2_1/lib/ruby/2.4./json/common.rb:156:in `parse'
    from (irb):1
```

Any advice on how to get my array of strings is appreciated.  Note I can't change the input (I can't remove the single quotes).

Comment: Where did you get this string? Just because it looks sort of like JSON doesn't mean it is JSON or that `JSON.parse` is the right tool for the job.

Comment: JSON doesn't allow single quotes to mark data?

Comment: No it doesn't, mrzasa has a link to the JSON standard in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49203172/479863). JSON is similar to JavaScript but they're not the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single quotes `'` are not valid string delimiters in JSON. You need to replace them with double quotes, e.g.:

```
JSON.parse("['de33']".gsub("'", "\""))
# => ["de33"]
```

[JSON standard](http://www.json.org/) says:

> A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in double quotes, using backslash escapes. A character is represented as a single character string. A string is very much like a C or Java string.